# Flex ComboBox in a Datagrid loses values when I scroll horizontally

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, combobox, renderer

I have a very strange problem in a Flex 3.4 Datagrid. One of the columns is a ComboBox - I have my own custom renderer for the ComboBox. I use it to select my data and then make a "save" to the db. Upon return the comboBox loses its value. Even stranger is that when I scroll the datagrid area to the left (by moving scrollbar right) - the values in the ComboBox change!! When I scroll the datagrid right (by moving the scrollbar left) - the values in the ComboBox don't change.

Has anyone seen anything remotely like this in a Flex app?

Thanks

Khalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item renderers get recylced, and its a pain sometimes!

Have a read [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/03/thinking_about_item_renderers_1.html) and google [this](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_en-GBGB346GB346&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=flex+item++renderers+recycle)

Basically you need to reset your values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Jammin - you are truely a star!

Firstly I could not believe that you answered my question within 1 minute of my posting it! Surely thats a new record, even for StackOverflow?

Second - I read the article by Alex - and learnt about renderer recycling. I'm used to Java Swing GUI (and even MFC), so this was quite a new (and confusing) concept for me. Still - managed to crack it after 2 hours. Can't say I *fully* understand it - but hey - it works!

Thanks again.

Khalid